# Pusher not working in AWS EC2 (Production Server)

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, websocket, pusher

Broadcasting.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
                'useTLS' => false
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Websockets.php

```
<?php

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Dashboard\Http\Middleware\Authorize;

return [

    /*
     * Set a custom dashboard configuration
     */
    'dashboard' => [
        'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
    ],

    /*
     * This package comes with multi tenancy out of the box. Here you can
     * configure the different apps that can use the webSockets server.
     *
     * Optionally you specify capacity so you can limit the maximum
     * concurrent connections for a specific app.
     *
     * Optionally you can disable client events so clients cannot send
     * messages to each other via the webSockets.
     */
    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
            'encrypted' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * This class is responsible for finding the apps. The default provider
     * will use the apps defined in this config file.
     *
     * You can create a custom provider by implementing the
     * `AppProvider` interface.
     */
    'app_provider' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\ConfigAppProvider::class,

    /*
     * This array contains the hosts of which you want to allow incoming requests.
     * Leave this empty if you want to accept requests from all hosts.
     */
    'allowed_origins' => [
        //
    ],

    /*
     * The maximum request size in kilobytes that is allowed for an incoming WebSocket request.
     */
    'max_request_size_in_kb' => 250,

    /*
     * This path will be used to register the necessary routes for the package.
     */
    'path' => 'laravel-websockets',

    /*
     * Dashboard Routes Middleware
     *
     * These middleware will be assigned to every dashboard route, giving you
     * the chance to add your own middleware to this list or change any of
     * the existing middleware. Or, you can simply stick with this list.
     */
    'middleware' => [
        'web',
        Authorize::class,
    ],

    'statistics' => [
        /*
         * This model will be used to store the statistics of the WebSocketsServer.
         * The only requirement is that the model should extend
         * `WebSocketsStatisticsEntry` provided by this package.
         */
        'model' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Models\WebSocketsStatisticsEntry::class,

        /**
         * The Statistics Logger will, by default, handle the incoming statistics, store them
         * and then release them into the database on each interval defined below.
         */
        'logger' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Logger\HttpStatisticsLogger::class,

        /*
         * Here you can specify the interval in seconds at which statistics should be logged.
         */
        'interval_in_seconds' => 60,

        /*
         * When the clean-command is executed, all recorded statistics older than
         * the number of days specified here will be deleted.
         */
        'delete_statistics_older_than_days' => 60,

        /*
         * Use an DNS resolver to make the requests to the statistics logger
         * default is to resolve everything to 127.0.0.1.
         */
        'perform_dns_lookup' => false,
    ],

    /*
     * Define the optional SSL context for your WebSocket connections.
     * You can see all available options at: http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php
     */


    'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => '/etc/certs/chain.cert',

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => '/etc/certs/private-key.key',

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => null,
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],

    /*
     * Channel Manager
     * This class handles how channel persistence is handled.
     * By default, persistence is stored in an array by the running webserver.
     * The only requirement is that the class should implement
     * `ChannelManager` interface provided by this package.
     */
    'channel_manager' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManagers\ArrayChannelManager::class,
];
```

It works perfectly fine in local server but doesn't in production. My server is AWS ec2 and i have enabled all incoming traffic

The Error
[image]

I have ran **php artisan config:cache**
Is there anything to be done on AWS's end or am i missing something to add on a linux server because my local server is windows